# Protecting backslash in korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, backslash, slash

I am trying to automate creation of a document with URLs using kshell. However when I try to enter a URL which looks similar to the line below, `\t` is tabbing and `\n` is creating  a new line. Can you tell me how to protect backslash (`\`) in this case?

The command

```
echo "\temp\naga"
```

outputs this

```
     emp
aga
```

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try using: `echo "\\temp\\naga"`

Comment: `how to protect backslash` The correct terminology is [escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), and as [Johan said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21737947/1454048), you just need an extra backslash.

Comment: if you're using `ksh`, read up on its far superior `print` function. (at the risk of making ksh code non-portable to other similar shells.). Good luck.

Comment: `echo` should not be considered portable, as there are many different implementations. `printf` is a much better choice.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
echo -E "\temp\naga"
```

man echo(1):

> -E   disable interpretation of backslash escapes

Answer (score 0):

To get special characters, you just put a `\` before it, so to get `\` you write `\\`.